# Make Error 127 -( obj/convolutioanl_kernels.o) while compiling Yolo (Darknet) with GPU=1

Tags: cuda, yolo, darknet

System Configuration: Ubuntu 16.04, Nvidia GTX 1060
Cuda Tool Kit: 9.0

I installed Cuda 9.0 on my system and am able to output nvidia-smi 
However, when I am trying to make darknet with GPU I am getting the following error:

> nvcc -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode
>   arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode
>   arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode
>   arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -gencode
>   arch=compute_61,code=[sm_61,compute_61] -DGPU
>   -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/convolutional_kernels.cu -o obj/convolutional_kernels.o /bin/sh:
>   nvcc: command not found make: *** [obj/convolutional_kernels.o] Error
>   127

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same error and found out that the cuda path was not correctly added.
These are some post installation steps necessary after CUDA installation. 
You might as well add them to your ~/.bashrc file.

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}

$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

[Post Installation Steps](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions)

Answer (score 0):

its fixed for me thx.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

i am using cuda 10.1 version and this also working for that version.

Answer (score 0):

It also worked for me thanks.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.5/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.5/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

I am using cuda 11.5 version so I just changed it.